# laravel api with react native post request

Tags: api, react-native, laravel-5, axios

I'm using `laravel` api as a backend and `react` native as a frontend.

I trying to post some data to my api which is sometimes added successfully and sometimes it give me  an error

> Request failed with status code 500

This is my api code:

```
public function addNumber(Request $request)
{
    $new = new ServiceRequest;
    $new->office_id = $request->office_id;
    $new->national_number = $request->national_number;
    $new->date = $request->date;
    $new->time = $request->time;
    $new->save();


    $detail = new ServiceRDetail ;
    $detail->request_id = $new->id;
    $detail->service_id  = $request->service_id;
    $detail->national_number = $request->national_number;   

    $detail->save();

    return response()->json(['success'=>'Added'],$this->successStatus); 

}
```

And this is my `react` native code:

```
manage = () => {


const national_number=this.state.pid;
const office_id=this.state.office_id;
const service_id=this.state.service_id;
const date=this.state.date;
const time=this.state.time;
 const  url='http://MyIP/api/add_number';
axios.post(url,{national_number,office_id,service_id,date,time})
.then(resp => alert('added')).catch(err => alert(err));


}
```

Comment: Have you checked the log file `storage/logs/laravel.log`. Also, this may fail because not all data is passed through the api, so saving will fail as there is now default data.

Comment: But also you have `ServiceRDetail` as a model class, is this supposed to be `ServiceDetail` instead?

Comment: i'm sure that the all data passed to api and i check the database

Comment: What has your log file said?

Comment: i'm tried to post data but there is no changed  in log file

Comment: Can you add `\Log::debug($request->all())` so we can see what is being passed. or `dd()` this. Either way we will get a result of what is being passed through to the controller